# Can I perform a token swap in raydium without pass amount in?

Tags: solana-program, raydium

Does anyone know if it is possible to swap a token X for SOL without informing the quantity? I would like to swap 100% of the balance available in the account, through raydium.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe so. You'll likely have to get token X's balance before initiating the swap.

From [raydium-amm/program/src/instruction.rs](https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-amm/blob/f290430a417569c3de514c43a17dad872ead59a2/program/src/instruction.rs#L90C1-L106C2), you can see the parameter is not Optional:

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Default, PartialEq)]
pub struct SwapInstructionBaseIn {
    // SOURCE amount to transfer, output to DESTINATION is based on the exchange rate
    pub amount_in: u64,
    /// Minimum amount of DESTINATION token to output, prevents excessive slippage
    pub minimum_amount_out: u64,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Default, PartialEq)]
pub struct SwapInstructionBaseOut {
    // SOURCE amount to transfer, output to DESTINATION is based on the exchange rate
    pub max_amount_in: u64,
    /// Minimum amount of DESTINATION token to output, prevents excessive slippage
    pub amount_out: u64,
}
```

To get your token balance you can pass the token account pubkey into the `getTokenAccountBalance` [method](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/solana/getTokenAccountBalance) in Solana-web3.js. Ex:

```
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
(async () => {
  const solana = new web3.Connection("YOUR_RPC_ENDPOINT");
  console.log(
    await solana.getTokenAccountBalance(
      new web3.PublicKey("YOUR_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS")
    )
  );
})();
```